# iOS CLLocationManager - do the region monitor manually

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

Although i know that the region monitoring supports iPhone4 and iPad2 only i want to implement this with the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method.

I have a method that get my saved region (place with latitude, longitude and radius) and my current location and i want to return true in case they are near each other.
My question is how do I calculate based on my information (both place and current location latitude,longitude and radius) if those places are near each other or not?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you have to manually code things out for the region. I found this article that may help you out.

[Getting GPS location, region in background...](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/30/location-region-data-in-background-on-ios4-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [distanceFromLocation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a)

```
CLLocation *current = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:long];
CLLocation *target = ...
CLLocationDistance meters = [current distanceFromLocation:target];
if (meters<radius) { /* you are closer than radius meters */ }
```